# Eclipse Theia with Graphical Language Server Platform

Tags: sequence-diagram, theia

I know it's bit theoretical question, but just wondering if anyone has done the GLSP with Eclipse or Theia ? if you can anyone give proper direction on same.

I just read their documentation, but couldn't get much idea or any direction which I should move forward.
So if anyone have tried before, please feel free to reply on same.

Thanks

Comment: This might help you: https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tag/glsp/

Comment: Take a look to the Coffee Editor example -> https://github.com/eclipse-emfcloud/coffee-editor (code) https://eclipsesource.com/coffee-editor (live application)